# jQuery Mobile Slider Steps not behaving when numbers are large

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-slider

I have a slider that is from 1 to 5 million, somehow jquery mobile optimizes the stepping to 50000 when using the slider despite me specifying the step to 1000. is there anyway to force override this behaviour

```
<form>
    <label for="slider-1">Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" min="0" max="5000000" value="10"    step="10" />
</form>
```

demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LSGAk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, you can't override it except if you're willing to change the source code of jQm.

The line that are the source of that behavior are in the function [refresh](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/forms/slider.js#L353). More precisely the following block:

```
if ( typeof val === "object" ) {
    data = val;
    // a slight tolerance helped get to the ends of the slider
    tol = 8;
    left = this.slider.offset().left;
    width = this.slider.width();
    pxStep = width/((max-min)/step);
    if ( !this.dragging ||
        data.pageX < left - tol ||
        data.pageX > left + width + tol ) {
            return;
    }
    if ( pxStep > 1 ) {
        percent = ( ( data.pageX - left ) / width ) * 100;
    } else {
        percent = Math.round( ( ( data.pageX - left ) / width ) * 100 );
    }
}
```

In the case of an interraction with the mouse/tap, val is an object and in your case pxStep is inferior to 1. So we have the round coming into action.

P.S: Not totally sure about what I wrote, it just had a quick glance at the code , but it seems to me that it behave this way.

Comment: Thank you!, i was about to go deep digging into the core after this but you were there ahead, I have disabled the percent step checking for now while thinking of a more comprehensive solution (modifying the maths).